# MySQLProfileProvider strange error

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I moved my asp.net application from one laptop to another.

The site is working ok but when I make login I receive this exception:

```
Parser Error Message: There was an error during profile provider initilization.

    Source Error: 


Line 263:               <clear/>
Line 264:               <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider"/>
Line 265:               <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="CM-CarpartsAuth"/>
Line 266:               <!--add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=5.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="CM-CarpartsAuth" /-->
Line 267:           </providers>
```

I do not understand why it's wrong here while this is working great on the previous machine.

Can you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...

Latest version of mysql installed seems to have some problems with respect to MySql Connector 6.2.2.0.

So, I dropped of MySQL Server 5.5.8 and installed 5.1.

Now, all it's ok...